# Having problems making a iterator for a singly linked list with a dummy header

Tags: java

```
class SinglyLinkedListIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {

        Node<T> current = null;

        public SinglyLinkedListIterator() {
            this.current = (Node<T>)header.getNext();
        }
        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return this.current.getNext() != null;
        }

        @Override
        public T next() {
            if (this.hasNext()) {
                T result= null;
                result = this.current.getElement();
                this.current = this.current.getNext();
                return result;
            }
            else {
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            }
        }

    }
```

This is the code i have as of now, the problem I have with it is that when it reaches the final node, the hasNext() condition does not hold true and i have no idea on how to make it work, if you guys could help id really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

You are off by a node. You initialize the iterator's `current` to the first node, so `hasNext` should be checking that `current != null`.